# Get all visible DIVs on a page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Another short Q, is there any short piece of code to get all DIVs on a page which have the visibility set to '`block`' or '`inline`'?

Thanks

Comment: Two questions: first, do you mean the CSS property `visibility` (in which case `inline` and `block` are not valid values) or `display`? Second, are you after all divs whose computed value (i.e. the effective value for the div, once all CSS rules have been taken into account) for `display`/`visibility` is `inline` or `block`, or just those for which the property has been explicitly set (either in JavaScript via the div's `style` property or via a style attribute in the div)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy with jQuery...

```
$("div:visible")
```

But if you want to be old school...

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
var elems = [];

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var div = divs[i];
  var vis = div.style.visibility;

  if(vis == 'block' || vis == 'inline')
    elems.push(div);
}
```

Comment: @Camran Answer updated.  I would recommend jQuery, it really speeds up development time and prevents headaches.

Comment: The non-jQuery version is flawed: I think you mean `display` rather than `visibility`, and it will only work when the display is explicitly set on the element's style. If you had a document containing some normal (visible) elements and no CSS, this function wouldn't return any elements. You need to use some combination of IE's `currentStyle` object and `getComputedStyle()` method to do this.

Comment: @Tim Wrong.  I answered what he asked (precisely).  Read the question, and then read my answer.  Camran doesn't say anything about `display`, and he does not say anything about elements that do not explicitly set the property.  Ok?  I know what you are saying, but that's not what he asked.  Thanks, and have a great day.

Comment: If anything, the jQuery version is flawed.

Comment: This isn't really worth arguing about, but I can't help myself. I take your point, but I think it's clear the OP either means `visbility` (in which case `inline` and `block` are invalid) or (more likely) means `display`. Also, it's not clear from the OP's phrasing whether he means what you've inferred (just elements with CSS `visibility` explicitly set to one of two invalid values)  or what I've inferred (any element whose computed CSS `display` is `inline` or `block`). Yours is a precise, literal reading of it; mine is (I'd say) the more natural and likely.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("div:visible")
```

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/