# addEventListener to an article element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, draggable, addeventlistener, getelementsbytagname, html5-draggable

I am trying to addEventListener to all article elements so when they are clicked it turns them into a draggable element.

I'm not using jQuery on this task.

Attempt 1:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ARTICLE").addEventListener('click', function(){
document.getElementsByTagName("ARTICLE").setAttribute('draggable', true);});
```

Attempt 2:

```
function draggableTrue() {
    var addDrag = document.getElementsByTagName("article");
    addDrag.setAttribute('draggable', true);
}

//add event listener to articles
var draggableArticles = document.getElementsByTagName("article");
draggableArticles.addEventListener('onclick', draggableTrue);
```

In both I am getting a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" which usually points out I am missing something, but after reading up I can't figure out what.

Comment: ARTICAL should be lower case

Comment: That doesn't really matter. http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/592610-var-anchors-document-getelementsbytagname

Comment: Yeah I had that first I was looking at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291061/get-all-visible-divs-on-a-page-with-javascript) and thought I'd try uppercase.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList, you should iterate over the returned list and then call the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementsByTagName returns a collection. So you need to iterate over it to add the event listeners. This collection is native DOM nodes collections and not a jquery collection hence you cannot use the addEventListener on the collection.

```
var articles = document.getElementsByTagName("ARTICLE");
var eventListener = function(){console.log('clicked an articles')}

for(var i=0; i<articles.length; i++){
    articles[i].addEventListener('click', eventListener );
}
```

Comment: Performance-wise, the handler should be defined outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your explanation! I saw the HTMLCollection (noted here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) but I put it down to inexperience on my behalf.

Comment: just to confirm, is it possible to 'setAttribute("draggable", true);' on the clicked article. I feel like I'm just creating a loop by trying to add .getElementsByTagName in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to check for your latters-cases.

But there is another issue, any code related to DOM elements has to be executed when that certain element is load (or is identified by Javascript Engine). The following event (onload) makes sure when the window is load, and then, it executes the closure assigned to. `window.onload = function(){}` is what you probably need.

```
window.onload = function(){
 // call your functions or document event listeners here
}
```

Also TagName, TagNameNS and ClassName all returns a collection which you have iterate through:

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for(var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++)
{
   allDivs[i].addEventListener();
}
```