# How to get visible elements with WebDriverIO

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I my tests I am using WebDriverIO. I want to get all elements with class **form_error** that are visible.

I try something like this:

`$$('.form_error:visible')`

but the :visible filter is not a valid webdriverio selector construct. 
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

WebdriverIO uses CSS selectors to find elements, and `:visible` is not a valid CSS selector.

Instead, you could go two ways:

1. Get all elements with a class of `.form_error`, then run `isVisible()` on them and filter the hidden ones out
2. Use a custom execute function to run JavaScript on the page to check for visibility of elements. Something similar to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2291076/150552)